# scale-free networks and adjacency matrix

Tags: graphs, computer-networks, adjacency-matrix

Given a distribution over graphs with $n$ nodes having the "scale-free" property, I would like to compute for a pair of vertices $(a,b)$ the probability that they are connected (or more precisely the probability that there is a directed edge from $a$ to $b$).

Is it possible to have such probability distribution ?

Note that the case without the "scale-free" property is not a problem. I can define the probability of having an edge from $a$ to $b$ as $P((a,b))=1/2$ for all $a, b$, $a \neq b$ in the graph.

Thank you.

Comment: all graphs have an adjacency matrix. try to reformulate your question. the adjacency matrix properties/ theory is sometimes used to generate scale-free networks.

Comment: @vzn Yes, all graphs have adjacency matrices. So it makes perfect sense to ask about the adjacency matrices of a particular class of graphs.

Comment: You are talking about probabilities, thus I assume that you have a distribution over graphs. So are you asking for an adjacency matrix regarding a graph or for a kind of adjacency matrix regarding your distribution ? It's not clear for me. Any way, the adjacency matrix and the graph are isomorph so you can compute both if you can compute one. The complexity for computing the adjacency matrix is at least quadratic in the vertices number, since it's just the matrix size.

Comment: I would like to generate this matrix only using probabilities.For instance, having t vertices, indexed 1, ..., t, I would like to be able to compute the probability of connection of a vertex i to a vertex j. Then I will be able to generate the matrix of a scale-free network.

Comment: @user7060 Can you choose those probabilities or not ?

Comment: @FrançoisGodi No, I don't know how to chose the probability distribution. Generating an adjacency matrix for a random network is easy: I just have to fix a probability of connection, for instance $1/2$, and make coin toss for each pair of vertices. I imagine that for scale-free networks, it isn't as easy as it looks.

Comment: @user7060 Ok.. So you are just asking for a probability such that when you generate a random graph where each possible edge is in the graph with this probability, then your graph is scale-free with high probability. I said graph and not adjacency matrix but we don't care, it's the same. I probably have the answer to your question, but please rewrite it clearly first.

Comment: Or more generally, you are looking for a distribution whose graphs are scale-free with h.p. Indeed I don't think it's possible with edge existence i.i.d..

Comment: Why do you care so much about generating your graphs by sampling edges independently?

Comment: The question as it is currently stated makes no sense.  Given a particular graph, either $a,b$ are connected or they aren't -- there's nothing probabilistic.  Maybe you mean "given a *distribution* over graphs", or "given a *random process" for generating a graph".  If so, you should edit the question accordingly -- and you need to tell us how the distribution/random process is specified, as that will dramatically affect the answer to your question.  As it stands, the question makes no sense and is not answerable in its current form.

Comment: I suspect that what you *actually* want is something totally different from what the question asks -- I suspect what you actually want is a distribution on graphs with some particular properties.  However, that's not what the question currently says.  If that's what you want: (a) you need to edit the question drastically to state this, (b) you need to more clearly state what properties you want the distribution to have, and (c) you probably ought to tell us what research you've done and what possibilities you've considered (and if you've rejected them, why).

Comment: @D.W. Thank you. I would like to edit the question appropriately but I don't know the good terminology... I have a not completely constructed network. I just have the nodes without edges. The only property that I want is "scale-free". I would like a probability distribution over the set of all pairs of vertices such that I can compute $P((a,b))=a\ certain\ value$ if an edge exists from $a$ to $b$. I edit my post to write that since the beginning "Given a network..." is ambiguous.

Comment: @D.W. I've edited the question.

Comment: @user7060 It's impossible to generate a scale free graph by just including each possible edge independently with some probability $p$. That gives a distribution known as [$G(n,p)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93R%C3%A9nyi_model), which looks nothing like scale-free graphs. For example, $G(n,p)$ graphs are fairly close to regular, whereas scale-free graphs are very far from regular.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Thanks. That's not possible even without  a preferential attachment model ? Look at the second paragraph in the answer below. "you have to decide in advance which vertices will have high degree and which will have low degree". Maybe I can define a probability distribution for the degrees of each vertices ? Not ? I suggest things... Given such a probability distribution, I could include each possible edge independently ? Or that does not work ?

Comment: @user7060 I don't know if preferential attachment is *necessary* but, as far as I know, it's the normal way of generating scale-free graphs. But, look, there's a large literature out there about how to do this -- you don't need to make up your own way of doing it.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I've read some slides on the subject but it's not clear how to do that. That's why I would like an example.

Comment: it looks like youve completely reformulated the question. suggest dropping by [chat] to work out more detail. maybe starting over. there seems to be a real question fighting to get free here. fyi the simple "probability" that any two edges are connected is just the number of edges divided by total possible edges $n^2$, unless there is some other defn wanted. and that does not discriminate the different types of graphs. in other words many non scale free graphs would have exactly the same probabilities and are much easier constructed. so think you probably need to rethink your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

The most popular generative model for scale-free networks is the [preferential attachment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barab%C3%A1si%E2%80%93Albert_model) model of Barabási and Albert. A graph is sampled using an iterative procedure. This is a different sampling procedure than you suggest, since the goal is not only to generate a certain degree sequence, but also to mimic other properties of real-life networks.

If all you're after is a certain degree sequence, you can use MCMC methods; see for example [Stanton and Pinar](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~isabelle/papers/alenex-jdd.pdf). Such algorithms don't conform to your type of algorithm, however. If you want to use your type of model, you have to decide in advance which vertices will have high degree and which will have low degree, since otherwise you will get a degree distribution which is either roughly Gaussian or roughly Poisson, but definitely no power law.

If all you're after is a certain degree sequence and you really want to use your own generative model, here is one possibility. Use the preferential attachment model, the algorithm of Stanton and Pinar, or any other randomized algorithm to generate a graph $G$. Now your model is: given two vertices $x,y$, if $(x,y) \in G$ then connect $x$ and $y$ with probability $1$, otherwise connect them with probability $0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact it's the opposite that I would like to have. I don't have a network at the beginning. I can assume a network in which there are nodes without the edges. Then I affect edges between some vertices using probabilities.

Comment: I gave such an approach in the second paragraph. In preprocessing, you generate a network using a less restricted model. Then you replicate this network using your model.

Comment: Thanks very much even if I did not understand the last paragraph. In particular the sentence "Now your model is: given two vertices x,y, if (x,y)∈G then connect x and y with probability 1, otherwise connect them with probability 0."

Comment: The thing is that every *deterministic* graph can be realized in your model. That is, for every graph $G$, we can choose edge probabilities so that you always get $G$. That's the tongue-in-cheek part of my answer. I'm always giving two other generative models.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Maybe my question has no sense, or I should reformulate it again.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is fairly unclear and it seems you lack basic understanding in the topic of scale-free networks. Congratulations! You now feel like almost every other PhD student ever. ;)

From how I understand your question, you would like to have a *probability distribution* over graphs such that you obtain a scale-free graph *with high probability* from this distribution. There are numerous ways of achieving that, and one of the most popular ones is the Preferential attachment model noted by Yuval.

It seems to me, however, that furthermore, you want to "grasp the individual edge probabilities by hand". Like the Erdos-Renyi random graph model $G(n,p)$, you want to basically know the $p$ for an edge given two nodes $u,v$. This is actually very hard to do for the preferential attachment model! (Though there exist results that do that).

But I have good news for you: This is possible! There are in fact several scale-free network models that give you exact edge probabilities and yet generate a scale-free graph in the end. The most famous one is probably the Chung-Lu Random Graph. The [first hit](http://www.math.duke.edu/~rtd/math777/c2s4.pdf) on google seems to give a very good introduction to the topic. Here's the gist of it:

1. First, for each vertex $i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$ choose a weight $w_i$ for that vertex. There are several appropriate ways to do this, but if you want something concrete you can use $w_i = \delta \cdot (n/i)^{1/(\beta - 1)}$. This will produce a scale-free network with power-law exponent $\beta$.
2. Second, connect two nodes with probability $p_{i,j} := \min\{1, \frac{w_i w_j}{\sum_k w_k}\}$

I hope this helps. If you have any further questions, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I imagine that $\frac{w_iw_j}{\sum w_k}$ can be greater than $1$. No ? What is $\delta$ ? Are the $w_i$ the preferential parameters ? What about the fitness model ?

Comment: If $\beta\leq 3$ then the sum can become larger than $1$. $\delta$ is just some constant, which will in the end adjust the average degree (which is $\Theta(\delta)$).
I am not sure what you refer to with "preferential parameters" or "fitness model". This model is different from the preferential attachment. 
The $w_i$ are the node weights; depending on how you chose them you get different degree sequences. If you choose them like I wrote you obtain a power law (= a scale-free network).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've seen the fitness model on Wiki ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-free_network)). In this model $p_{i,j}$ can be computed as $\frac{\delta x_ix_j}{1+\delta x_ix_j}$ where $x_i$, $x_j$ are fitness assigned to nodes $i$ and $j$. Maybe these fitness values are chosen following a power law, I don't know...

Comment: It is a slight variation, but has basically the same properties as my suggestion when you choose (their) $\delta$ to be $1/\sum_k w_k$. There exist many many slight variations on this model.

Comment: Thank you very much. Why we have a probability with a max in the model you propose while in the other model the probability calculation is simpler ?

Comment: Good question. You can use the other probability, if you like. It turns out, however, that the ugliness is roughly the same in both cases, depending on what you actually want to compute...